# Simple MPI parallelization of FOR-LOOP

Tags: for-loop, mpi

I am trying to do simple MPI distribution of for-loop iterations to “Worker” cores. The “Workers” should do the job (take vector of size “nGenes” in format double, typically ~6 in size) and send back the result (one variable in format double). But, I have trouble even with the first step, passing messages from “Master” core (0) to “Worker” cores (1,2,…,nWorkers). The program goes through the send messages part, but it’s stacked in the receiving part where the line with MPI_Recv(…) is. I can't see what might be the problem. Please help.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */

double fR(double a);
void Calculate_MPI_Division_of_Work_Per_Core_Master0AndSlaves(int Number_of_Tasks, int NumberOfProcessors, int* START_on_core, int* END_on_core);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int nIndividuals = 10;
int nGenes = 6;

double** DATA;
DATA = new double* [nIndividuals];
for (int ii=0; ii<nIndividuals; ii++)
{
    DATA[ii] = new double [nGenes];
}
for (int ii=0; ii<nIndividuals; ii++)
{
    for (int jj=0; jj<nGenes; jj++)
    {
        DATA[ii][jj] = ii+jj; // random intialization of the elements.
    }
}

int MyRank, NumberOfProcessors;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyRank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NumberOfProcessors);
int NumberOfWorkers = NumberOfProcessors - 1;

int* Iteration_START_on_core;
int* Iteration_STOP_on_core;
Iteration_START_on_core = new int [NumberOfWorkers+1];
Iteration_STOP_on_core  = new int [NumberOfWorkers+1];

Calculate_MPI_Division_of_Work_Per_Core_Master0AndSlaves(nIndividuals, NumberOfProcessors, Iteration_START_on_core, Iteration_STOP_on_core);


if (MyRank == 0)
{
    std::cout << " ======================== " << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NumberOfProcessors=" << NumberOfProcessors << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NumberOfWorkers=   " << NumberOfWorkers    << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NumberOfTasks=     " << nIndividuals       << std::endl;
    for (int ww=0; ww<=NumberOfWorkers; ww++)
    {
        std::cout << "(Core: " << ww << ")  S:" << Iteration_START_on_core[ww] << "   E:" << Iteration_STOP_on_core[ww] << "   LoadOnCore: ";
        if (ww==0)
        {
            std::cout << 0 ;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << Iteration_STOP_on_core[ww] - Iteration_START_on_core[ww] +1;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << " ======================== " << std::endl;
}/// End_If(MyRank==0)


if (MyRank == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Start Sending...." << std::endl ;

    double* sendbuff;
    sendbuff = new double [nGenes];

    for (int cc=1; cc<=NumberOfWorkers; cc++)
    {
        for (int jj=Iteration_START_on_core[cc]; jj<=Iteration_STOP_on_core[cc]; jj++)
        {


            for (int gg=0; gg<nGenes; gg++)
            {
                sendbuff[gg] = DATA[jj][gg];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl << "SEND to Core " << cc << ": Start=" << Iteration_START_on_core[cc] << ", End=" << Iteration_STOP_on_core[cc] << ". Taks#: " << jj << " -- DATA: ";
            MPI_Send(&sendbuff, nGenes, MPI_DOUBLE, cc, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            for (int mm=0; mm<nGenes; mm++)
            {
                std::cout << DATA[jj][mm] << " | ";
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete[] sendbuff;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Finish sending." << std::endl ;
}
else
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "...Worker Cores..." << std::endl ;


    for (int cc=1; cc<=NumberOfWorkers; cc++)
    {
        if (MyRank == cc)
        {
            MPI_Status status;

            double* receivebuff;
            receivebuff = new double [nGenes];
            //std::cout << "Start Receiving on Core " << cc << ".  FROM job: " << Iteration_START_on_core[cc] << "  TO job: " << Iteration_STOP_on_core[cc] << "." << std::endl ;
            for (int kk=Iteration_START_on_core[cc]; kk<=Iteration_STOP_on_core[cc]; kk++)
            {

                MPI_Recv(&receivebuff, nGenes, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                std::cout << std::endl << "RECEIVE on Core: " << cc << ". From Core " << 0 << ": Start=" << Iteration_START_on_core[cc] << ", End=" << Iteration_STOP_on_core[cc] << ". Work on task: " << kk << ".";
                std::cout << " | ";
                for (int aa=0; aa<nGenes; aa++)
                {
                    std::cout << receivebuff[aa] << " | ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            delete [] receivebuff;
            std::cout << std::endl << "Finish receiving on core " << cc << "." << std::endl ;
        }
    }
}

for (int ii=1; ii<nIndividuals; ii++)
{
    delete[] DATA[ii];
}
delete[] DATA;

if (MyRank==0) std::cout << std::endl << "Prepare to MPI_Finalize ... " << std::endl ;
   MPI_Finalize();
if (MyRank==0) std::cout << std::endl << "... Completed MPI_Finalize. " << std::endl ;
///######################################################################################################


return 0;
} /// END MAIN PROGRAM



///===========================================================================================================================
///
///  Function: MPI Division of Work per Core.

void Calculate_MPI_Division_of_Work_Per_Core_Master0AndSlaves(int Number_of_Tasks, int NumberOfProcessors, int* START_on_core, int* END_on_core)
{
    int NuberOfWorkers = NumberOfProcessors-1;
    int integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker = floor(Number_of_Tasks/NuberOfWorkers);
    int reminder_Num_Taska_Per_Worker = Number_of_Tasks - integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker*NuberOfWorkers;

    START_on_core[0] = -1;
    END_on_core[0]   = -1;
    //std::cout << std::endl << "F: integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker  = " << integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker  << std::endl;
    //std::cout              << "F: reminder_Num_Taska_Per_Worker = " << reminder_Num_Taska_Per_Worker << std::endl;

    if (reminder_Num_Taska_Per_Worker==0)
    {
        START_on_core[1] = 0;
        END_on_core[1]   = START_on_core[1] + integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker - 1;

        for (int iProcess=2; iProcess<NumberOfProcessors; iProcess++)
        {
            START_on_core[iProcess] =  START_on_core[iProcess-1] + integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker;
            END_on_core[iProcess]   =  END_on_core[iProcess-1]   + integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        START_on_core[1] = 0;
        END_on_core[1]   = START_on_core[1] + integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker - 1 + 1;

        for (int iProcess=2; iProcess<reminder_Num_Taska_Per_Worker+1; iProcess++)
        {
            START_on_core[iProcess] =  START_on_core[iProcess-1] + integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker+1;
            END_on_core[iProcess]   =  END_on_core[iProcess-1]   + integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker+1;
        }
        for (int iProcess=reminder_Num_Taska_Per_Worker+1; iProcess<NumberOfProcessors; iProcess++)
        {
            START_on_core[iProcess] =  END_on_core[iProcess-1]  +1;
            END_on_core[iProcess]   =  START_on_core[iProcess]  +integer_Num_Tasks_Per_Worker-1;
        }
    }
//
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is you are not using send and receive buffers correctly.
`sendbuff` and `receivebuff` are pointers, so use them directly instead of their address.

```
MPI_Send(&sendbuff, nGenes, MPI_DOUBLE, cc, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Recv(&receivebuff, nGenes, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

must be replaced with

```
MPI_Send(sendbuff, nGenes, MPI_DOUBLE, cc, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Recv(receivebuff, nGenes, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

As a side note, you do not need to use an intermediate buffer to send data, and you can simply

```
MPI_Send(DATA[jj], nGenes, MPI_DOUBLE, cc, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Also, there is no need for an outermost loop in the receive part

```
for (int cc=1; cc<=NumberOfWorkers; cc++)
    if (MyRank == cc)
```

could be simply be replaced with

```
cc = MyRank
```

Last but not least, you can learn about `MPI_Scatterv()` or even `MPI_Scatter()` and inter-communicator, it is likely the best fit for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks very much Gilles! It all worked out! Do you have good reference book/website to recommend for quick learning of MPI basics?

Comment: Hi Gilles, could I ask you one more question, please? I've extended the code to do a calculation on the WORKER cores and then send back result to the MASTER core (rank=0). That part was only able to compile and run properly if I did following Send/Recv with the address ("&") of the buffers and the buffers had to be 1-dim arrays:                MPI_Send(&FF[0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE,0,1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);               

 MPI_Recv(&RcVal[0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, cc, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);    It works, but I am buffeld why.

Comment: if you declare `double * FF;` then `FF` is equivalent to `&FF[0]`. `&FF` is something very different that cannot be used in this context. does this answer your question ? if you are looking for a quick tutorial, you can start at http://mpitutorial.com/ Bill Gropp and others wrote 3 books about MPI and volume 1 should answer most of your questions (not a small book though)

Comment: The declaration was: double FF[1]; Thanks for the book recommendation.